# Make the colors in the tag editor match the actual tag colors on Meta sites

Tags: feature-request, tags, meta, editor

In the posting view, or the edit view, its color is like this:

[image]

But in the post view, its color is like this (this is another question):

[image]

Why are the colors different? Can we change them to the same color?

Comment: Seems like good UX to me that there is a distinguishable difference between editable version and static printed display

Comment: @charlietfl I disagree in this specific case, especially when they appear to match on main. And the first dark-grey tag on meta is the same color as the final version, while the blue is not.